# Saving workouts in HealthKit

Tags: ios, ios8, healthkit

I'm trying to save a workout in HealthKit. Here's my code:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

self.healthStore = [[HKHealthStore alloc] init];
[self.healthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:[HKWorkoutType workoutType]] readTypes:nil completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

    if (success){

        HKWorkout *workout = [HKWorkout workoutWithActivityType:HKWorkoutActivityTypeRunning startDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-3600] endDate:[NSDate date] duration:3600 totalEnergyBurned:[HKQuantity quantityWithUnit:[HKUnit calorieUnit] doubleValue:100.0] totalDistance:[HKQuantity quantityWithUnit:[HKUnit meterUnit] doubleValue:5000.0] metadata:nil];

        __strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        [strongSelf.healthStore saveObject:workout withCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Success? %d", success);
            if (error){
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            }
        }];
    }

}];
```

After prompting the user for permission (and accepting), this code creates a running activity that lasts for 1 hour, burns 100 calories and has a distance of 5000m.

Saving the workout to the HKHealthStore gives a success value of YES, and a nil error - so at this point, I'd expect it would be there.

However, on opening the Health app I'm unable to find the workout, distance or calories burned. What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is expected behavior in iOS 8.  Workouts do not appear in the Health app, but you should still be able to query for them.  Calories and distance from a workout will only show up in Health if you also save calorie/distance samples associated with that workout by using **-[HKHealthStore addSamples:toWorkout:completion]**.

Comment: Thanks! I've also filed this as a "feature request" radar - rdar://18391800

Comment: Quick question... once you `addSamples:toWorkout`... how can you get them again?

Answer (score 0):

Use [HKHealthStore addSamples:toWorkout:completion].
for more information http://eriphonedeveloper.wordpress.com/2014/09/30/a-soft-touch-of-apple-healthkit-healthkit-tutorial/